# entity framework core 2 linking to many to many

Tags: many-to-many, entity-framework-core

This is my model and it has a many to many relationship set up between learning programme and learning module. The next thing to do which I’m not sure which is best practice is the table learning release. This needs a 1 to many connection to this many to many LearningProgrammeAssignment. Do I need to create an ID in LearningProgrammeAssignment? Or can I just reference it in LearningRelease?

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<LearningProgramme> LearningProgrammes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LearningModule> LearningModules { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LearningProgrammeAssignment> LearningProgrammeAssignments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LearningRelease> LearningReleases { get; set; }

}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<LearningProgrammeAssignment>()
            .HasKey(p => new { p.LearningModuleId, p.LearningProgrammeId });
    }

public class LearningProgramme
{
 public int LearningProgrammeId { get; set; }
 public string LearningProgrammeTitle { get; set; }
 public List<LearningProgrammeAssignment> LearningProgrammeAssignments { get; set; }
}

public class LearningModule
{
  public int LearningModuleId { get; set; }
  public string LearningModuleTitle { get; set; }
 public List<LearningProgrammeAssignment> LearningProgrammeAssignments { get; set; }
}

public class LearningProgrammeAssignment
{
    public int LearningProgrammeId { get; set; }
    public int LearningModuleId { get; set; }
    public LearningProgramme LearningProgramme { get; set; }
    public LearningModule LearningModule { get; set; }
}

public class LearningRelease
{
 public int LearningReleaseId { get; set; }
 public int systemcode { get; set; }
 public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }   
     //add in the LearningProgrammeAssignment id 
}
```

Comment: It looks like `LearningProgrammeAssignment` is not just a join table. You might be better off adding its own primary key as you thought of. Then you can relate it to `LearningRelease` like a normal entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want a one-to-many relationship between `LearningRelease` and `LearningProgrammeAssignment`, you do need to define a `LearningReleaseId` inside `LearningProgrammeAssignment` as the foreign key in order to setup the relationship correctly:

```csharp
namespace DL.SO.EFCore.Learning.Data.Entities
{
    public class LearningProgrammeAssignment
    {
        public int LearningProgrammeId { get; set; }
        public LearningProgramme LearningProgramme { get; set; }

        public int LearningModuleId { get; set; }
        public LearningModule LearningModule { get; set; }

        public int LearningReleaseId { get; set; }
        // Optional
        public LearningRelease LearningRelease { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The navigation property `LearningRelease` is optional. It depends on whether you want it or not. Same for the "many" relationship inside `LearningRelease`:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DL.SO.EFCore.Learning.Data.Entities
{
    public class LearningRelease
    {
        public int LearningReleaseId { get; set; }
        public int SystemCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        public List<LearningProgrammeAssignment> LearningProgrammeAssignments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to configure them in the normal way:

```csharp
using DL.SO.EFCore.Learning.Data.Configurations;
using DL.SO.EFCore.Learning.Data.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DL.SO.EFCore.Learning.Data
{
    public class LearningDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public LearningDbContext(DbContextOptions<LearningDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<LearningModule> LearningModules { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LearningProgramme> LearningProgrammes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LearningProgrammeAssignment> LearningProgrammeAssignments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LearningRelease> LearningReleases { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new LearningModuleConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new LearningProgrammeConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new LearningProgrammeAssignmentConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new LearningReleaseConfiguration());
        }
    }
}
```

The key is in `LearningProgrammeAssignmentConfiguration` (other configurations are not posted for clarity):

```csharp
using DL.SO.EFCore.Learning.Data.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace DL.SO.EFCore.Learning.Data.Configurations
{
    public class LearningProgrammeAssignmentConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<LearningProgrammeAssignment>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LearningProgrammeAssignment> builder)
        {
            // Composite key
            builder.HasKey(x => new { x.LearningModuleId, x.LearningProgrammeId });

            // Setup Many-To-Many relationship between LearningModule and LearningProgramme
            builder.HasOne(x => x.LearningModule)
                .WithMany(x => x.LearningProgrammeAssignments)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.LearningModuleId);

            builder.HasOne(x => x.LearningProgramme)
                .WithMany(x => x.LearningProgrammeAssignments)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.LearningProgrammeId);

            // Setup One-To-Many relationship between LearningRelease and LearningProgrammeAssignment
            builder.HasOne(x => x.LearningRelease)
                .WithMany(x => x.LearningProgrammeAssignments)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.LearningReleaseId);

            // Alternately:
            //   you don't have to put the navigation property LearningRelease 
            //   in this LearningProgrammeAssignment, as you can setup 
            //   One-To-Many relationship without navigation properties like 
            //   this:
            //builder.HasOne<LearningRelease>()
            //    .WithMany()
            //    .HasForeignKey(x => x.LearningReleaseId);

            builder.ToTable("LearningProgrammeAssignment");
        }
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you David, perfect explanation